# Drupal cache expire value of -1?

Tags: 7, caching

What does a value of -1 mean when it's present in the expire field of a cache entry in the database?  I've honestly looked around and could not find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is coming from includes/bootstrap.inc:

```
/**
 * Indicates that the item should be removed at the next general cache wipe.
 */
define('CACHE_TEMPORARY', -1);
```

Which is also defined in the docblock for [`cache_set($cid, $data, $bin, $expire)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7):

> `$expire`: One of the following values:
>  
>    - `CACHE_PERMANENT`: Indicates that the item should never be removed unless explicitly told to using cache_clear_all() with a cache ID.
>    - `CACHE_TEMPORARY`: Indicates that the item should be removed at the next general cache wipe.
>    - A Unix timestamp: Indicates that the item should be kept at least until the given time, after which it behaves like `CACHE_TEMPORARY`.